# MenuItem.Icon loses its image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a Resource like;

```
  <Window.Resources>

    <MenuItem Header="*Rename" x:Key="ctxItem" x:Name="removeItem" Click="removeItem_Click" Padding="5,5,5,5">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="../images/removeitem.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
```

In code behind i do the following;

```
ContextMenu ctxTmp = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem mni = ((MenuItem)this.Resources["ctxItem"]);
        MenuItem mniTmp = new MenuItem();
        mniTmp.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(removeItem_Click);
        mniTmp.Name = "removeItem" + x;
        mniTmp.Tag = pic;
        mniTmp.Icon = mni.Icon;
        mniTmp.Header = mni.Header;
        mniTmp.CommandTarget = pic;
        ctxTmp.Items.Add(mniTmp);
        x++;
        return ctxTmp;
```

And set my object's ContextMenu to the returning item.

The behaviour is like this:
It displays my UIelement in the needed canvas, and the contextMenu is fine.
But when i add a second object. Context menu still works, but the image i'm using is not shown.It's wierd and couldn't figured it out.

Thanks Poyraz

Comment: do you also have the same issue when you set the image's source path to an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that your Image Source path works.
According to this web [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx), I will transform your path :

```
Source="../images/removeitem.png"
```

into URI

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/images/removeitem.png"
```

Comment: Actually, either one will work. It is unnecessary to add the pack prefix before the relative path because the will be interpreted as relative to the application directory.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse the same Image element in two MenuItems. You are effectively putting the same visual in two locations, which is not allowed. You would need to create a new instance of Image, even if it points to the same image.

You can however reuse instances of ImageSource.